# Outlook create new .ost file and than argues that it is outdated

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I often run into following error:
[image]

However before the start of outlook there is no .ost file. When Outlook starts it's get created and Outlook presents the error dialog.

The used Operating System is Windows 8 64bit. The exchange server is 2010.

We have this problem on one of our test systems where we perform ui tests using Microsoft Test Maneger 2010. Before the test starts we restore to a clean snapshot.

Searching for this problem the answers normaly asumes that an old file got coruppted and should just deleted and recreated. But in our case the file does not exists in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I migrated the Exchangeserver to 2016 an the problem is gone.
Unfortunatly I havent found a way to get rid of this problem in the 2010 edition of exchange server.

So resolution is Update. (if you can)

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes up in some clients (depending on the patch level) due to the reason that the Exchange Cache mode is enforced on the server side, but the client isn´t configured to use the Exchange Cache mode. So check if you use the correct configuration.